# How to prevent user from inputting the wrong time format for a Visio document?

Tags: vba, visio

I created an InputBox where the user inputs time.
I created a loop to prevent the user from inputting letters or to limit the length of the input of time to four digit.

How do I prevent the user from inputting the wrong time format?

Example: I'm trying to prevent time as 1566 (military time) or 2500.

```vb
Sub BackGroundTime()
    Dim shpNum As Integer
    Dim ADate As String
    Dim formTime As String
    
    Set shp = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection(1)
    shpNum = shp.ID
    
    formTime = Format(LongTime, "HHmm")
    formTime = InputBox("Enter Time", "Time")

    Do Until IsNumeric(formDate) And Len(formDate) = 4

        formDate = InputBox("Enter Time", "Time")
        If IsNumeric(formDate) And Len(formDate) = 4 Then
            Set vsoCharacters1 = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(shpNum).Characters

            Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(shpNum).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowFill, visFillForegnd).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,255,255))"

            vsoCharacters1.TExt = formDate

        ElseIf formDate = "" Then
            Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(shpNum).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowFill, visFillForegnd).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,255,102))"
            Exit Do
        Else
            MsgBox ("Please check your input for 'Time'. The time format must be four digits and no letters")
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have VBA parse the date input by the user, and then you can format it precisely how you want it to be. That's probably going to be the most reliable way to do it.

```
Function ParseUserDate(DateStr As String, ByRef ValidDate As Boolean) As Date
    On Error Resume Next
        Dim DateVal As Date
        DateVal = CDate(DateStr)
        ValidDate = (Err.Number = 0)
        If ValidDate Then ParseUserDate = DateVal
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

You can add a function like above, and if ValidDate comes back false then you warn the user, otherwise you format the returned date value.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't respond to this earlier.  Thank you Big Ben for editing my code (I was having problems trying to format it) Also, thank you Jon Fournier for answering my question.

Comment: I have a question.  For the Function above, do I reference that to the code I provided above?  or do I replace my code above with your function.  I'm sorry for asking this..I'm new to coding and don't know how to link the function.